# Is this a correct foreign key relationship standard?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, entity, entity-relationship

Let's assume I have 3 tables and sorted from parents to child:

- `Table A` (column `AId`)
- `Table B` (columns `BId`, `AId`)
- `Table C` (columns `CId`, `AId`, `BId`)

`Table B.AId` is referencing `Table A.AId`.

`Table C.BId` is linked to `Table B.BId` and `Table C.AId` is linked to `Table B.AId` - not `Table A.AId`.

Can I know whether this is correct standard or not? Explain with more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard"? What are PK for the named tables?

Answer (score 0):

Answer *might* depend on database you actually use.

I'm on Oracle, and - from its perspective - your approach wouldn't work because foreign key **must** reference primary (or unique) key in another table.

It means that the first two tables can be created with no problems:

```
SQL> create table table_a
  2    (aid number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table table_b
  2    (bid number primary key,
  3     aid number references table_a (aid));

Table created.
```

However, `table_c` would fail because `aid` is trying to reference `table_b.aid`, but that column is **not** primary key in `table_b`:

```
SQL> create table table_c
  2    (cid number primary key,
  3     bid number references table_b (bid),
  4     aid number references table_b (aid));
   aid number references table_b (aid))
                                  *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

However, if `table_c.aid` references `table_a.aid` (a primary key column), everything is OK:

```
SQL> create table table_c
  2    (cid number primary key,
  3     bid number references table_b (bid),
  4     aid number references table_a (aid));

Table created.
```

---

Alternative approach (although this is NOT what you described) would be a composite primary (and then foreign) key:

```
SQL> drop table table_c;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop table table_b;

Table dropped.
```

Composite primary key:

```
SQL> create table table_b
  2    (bid number,
  3     aid number references table_a (aid),
  4     --
  5     constraint pk_b primary key (bid, aid));

Table created.
```

`table_c` still can't reference `table_b`'s columns *separately*:

```
SQL> create table table_c
  2    (cid number primary key,
  3     bid number references table_b (bid),
  4     aid number references table_b (aid));
   bid number references table_b (bid),
                                  *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

Composite foreign key is OK:

```
SQL> create table table_c
  2    (cid number primary key,
  3     bid number,
  4     aid number,
  5     --
  6     constraint fk_cb foreign key (bid, aid) references table_b (bid, aid));

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

If your database supports foreign keys that reference *any* column (which doesn't have to be primary/unique key), you'd probably be able to create such a data model. Is it correct? Can't tell, you should know why you want to reference columns that way. If it were me, I'd reference `table_a.aid` from `table_c.aid`.

Comment: Is it still correct standard even they are unique and part of primary Key..

Table A.AId is a PK and in Table B.AId is a Pk and FK (of Table A), then Table C.AId is a FK (of Table B)

Comment: Can't try it right now, but - as far as I can tell - yes, that would work as (in that case) C.AID references TABLE_B's primary key (B.AID).